# Net::HTTP.get show progress

Tags: ruby

```
require 'net/http'

File.write(file_name, Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url)))
```

I want to show to the user what's happening here, something like progress because the size of a file can be big. But only the information the user can be interested in, not all the debug information.

Does `Net::HTTP.get` have such an ability?

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 6):

You can find information on that here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Streaming+Response+Bodies

The example snippet used in the docs for just such a thing is:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("http://apps.sfgov.org/datafiles/view.php?file=sfgis/citylots.zip")

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  http.request request do |response|
    file_size = response['content-length'].to_i
    amount_downloaded = 0

    open 'large_file', 'wb' do |io| # 'b' opens the file in binary mode 
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        io.write chunk
        amount_downloaded += chunk.size
        puts "%.2f%" % (amount_downloaded.to_f / file_size * 100)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: your example shows only that something is happening, but that's not exactly what I want. I want a progress in percent.

Comment: fair enough ... edited to show the percents with an actual dummy file of JSON from SF public data.